# Split a gird n*m to sub-girds a*b

Tags: c#, arrays, list, linq, grid

There is a grid 9*9 and I want to split it into 9 grids of 3*3.

```
char[][] grid = new[]
{
    new[] {'.', '.', '.', '1', '4', '.', '.', '2', '.'}, 
    new[] {'.', '.', '6', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
    new[] {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
    new[] {'.', '.', '1', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
    new[] {'.', '6', '7', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '9'},
    new[] {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '8', '1', '.'},
    new[] {'.', '3', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '6'},
    new[] {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '7', '.', '.', '.'},
    new[] {'.', '.', '.', '5', '.', '.', '.', '7', '.'}
};
```

Here is my solution that works:

```
List<char[][]> myList = new List<char[][]>();
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i = i + 3)
    {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j = j + 3)
    {
        List<char[]> temp1 = new List<char[]>();
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {
            List<char> temp2 = new List<char>();
            for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
            {
                temp2.Add(grid[i + k][j + l]);
            }
            temp1.Add(temp2.ToArray());
        }
        myList.Add(temp1.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Looking for more simple way to do it, specially Linq solution. Even though it is not as efficient as this one. Less lines of code is more important in this case.

Comment: You could get every third element with `i % 3 == 0` and do it all in two loops. One that loops over every array, and one that checks if it's the third element and splits accordingly.

Comment: Do you have a preference on where you want to 'split' the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use *modulo arithmetics*:

```
  int size = 3; 

  var grids = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 9)
    .Select(index => grid            
      .Skip(index / size * size)     // Y coordinates 0..2, 3..5, 6..8
      .Take(size)
      .Select(line => line
         .Skip(index % size * size)  // X coordinates 0..2, 3..5, 6..8
         .Take(size))
         .ToArray()
      .ToArray())
    .ToArray(); // final materialization into char[][][] (if required)
```

Test:

```
  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine, grids
    .Select(cell => string.Join(Environment.NewLine, cell
       .Select(line => string.Join(" ", line)))));

  Console.WriteLine(report);
```

Outcome:

```
. . .
. . 6
. . .

1 4 .
. . .
. . .

. 2 .
. . .
. . .

. . 1
. 6 7
. . .

. . .
. . .
. . .

. . .
. . 9
8 1 .

. 3 .
. . .
. . .

. . .
. . 7
5 . .

. . 6
. . .
. 7 .
```